# An algorithm that is $O(n^{\log(n)})$

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, asymptotics

After having searched for a while, and after having read this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592649/examples-of-algorithms-which-has-o1-on-log-n-and-olog-n-complexities

I was just wondering: is there some example of algorithm whose time complexity is ?$$O(n^{\log(n)})$$

Sorry for the arid question, I would just like to know if there is some example, being this a function that grows faster than polynomials but slower than exponentials.

Comment: Technically, any algorithm that has a complexity lower than $O(n^{\log n})$ answers the question. And for a tight bound, just a loop that counts from $1$ to $n^{\log n}$. So you should strengthen the requirement for the question to be interesting.

Comment: There is a TCS.SE question asking for a natural problem with a quasi-polynomial time algorithm https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/33076/is-there-a-natural-problem-in-quasi-polynomial-time-but-not-in-polynomial-time

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there are examples, though I don't know of any elementary ones. Before I give one, notice that
$$
n^{\log n} = (2^{\log n})^{\log n} = 2^{(\log n)^2} = O(2^{\text{poly}(\log n)})
$$

where $\text{poly}$ is a polynomial function (in this case quadratic).
For this reason, the time complexity you are interested in ($n^{\log n}$) is an example of **quasi-polynomial time** (QP) - it's two to the power of a polynomial function of $\log n$.

Quasi-polynomial time is somewhat unusual to encounter, but by the [time hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem), we know that there are decision problems that require any complexity bound we might be interested in, including quasi-polynomial time. That includes that there must be problems that require $n^{\log n}$ (up to a logarithmic factor). But that doesn't mean that any of those examples is necessarily natural.

Perhaps the most famous examples of quasi-polynomial time algorithms are:

1. The best known algorithm for the [graph isomorphism problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem). The graph isomorphism problem is, on input two graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$, are $G_1$ and $G_2$ isomorphic? László Babai proposed an algorithm in 2017 which runs in quasipolynomial time.
2. The best known algorithm for the [parity game problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_game), which has time $O(n^{\log n + 6})$. (See [this paper](https://researchspace.auckland.ac.nz/bitstream/handle/2292/31757/500Cris.pdf?sequence=1).)

Neither of these algorithms is known to be asymptotically optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to compute $$\binom{n}{k}$$ for given $k$ and $n$. A simple way is to use brute-force that running time will be $O(n^{k})$. Now if we set $k=O(\log n)$ we achieved desired bound.